# Compare strings in SQL

Tags: sql

I am in a situation where I need to return results if some conditions on the string/character are met.

**For example:** to return only the names that contain 'F' character from the `Person` table.

How to create an SQL query based on such conditions? Is there any link to a documentation that explains how can SQL perform such queries?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This can depend on the database engine you are using.  For most implementations, I encourage you to research the LIKE keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most RDBMS offer string operations which are able to perform that required task in one way or the other.

In MySQL you might use [`INSTR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_instr):

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE INSTR(Person, 'F') > 0;
```

In [Oracle, this can be done](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions068.htm), too.

In PostgreSQL, you can use [`STRPOS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html):

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE strpos(Person, 'F') > 0;
```

Usually there are several approaches to solve this, many would choose the `LIKE` operator. For more details, please refer to the documentation of the RDBMS of your choice.

**Update**

As requested by the questioner a few words about the `LIKE` operator, which are used not only in [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) or [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions016.htm), but in other RDBMS, too.

The use of `LIKE` will in some cases make your RDBMS try to use an index, it usually does not not try to do so if you use a string functions.

Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE Person LIKE 'F%';
```

Comment: I checked for Oracle and MySQL and both they have the SQL LIKE. Can you please give us your insight about this (As an edit). Thanks again. (PS: I am not developping any solution, it is a question in a concours where the RDBMS is not specified)

Comment: I've added a few words regarding the `LIKE` operator.

Answer (score 2):

The most basic approach is to use `LIKE` operator:

```
-- name starts with 'F' 
SELECT * FROM person WHERE name LIKE 'F%'

-- name contains 'F'
SELECT * FROM person WHERE name LIKE '%F%'
```

(`%` is a wildcard)

Answer (score 1):

The query may look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE FirstName LIKE '%F%' OR LastName LIKE '%F%'
```